Difference between partial key and partial primary key - Database theory
Is there any difference between partial key and partial primary key?
Partial primary key is an attribute of an entity and it constitutes the primary key of the entity itself.
What about the partial key? Is it synomym of partial primary key? I found the "partial primary key" when I studied entities in general. Instead I found "partial key" when I studied weak entities.
